# Querying multiple taxonomies in URL leads to wrong taxonomy archive

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

My problem is very basic but so far I have not managed to solve it so I'll just post it here and hope one of you has got an idea.

Basically, I have two custom taxonomies "autor" (writer) and "sprache" (language) for a custom post type that I want to use in an url like this:
... blog/datenbank/autor/steve-perry/?sprache=deutsch

In the example, I want the "autor" archive page (Steve Perry) to show only the posts tagged with the language "deutsch". However, wordpress instead shows me the taxonomy archive template for "sprache" with the results for the author Steve Perry.

In other words, Wordpress shows me this page
... blog/datenbank/sprache/deutsch/
with the results narrowed down to everything tagged "Steve Perry"

But I want it to show this page
... blog/datenbank/autor/steve-perry/
with the results narrowed down to everything tagged "Deutsch"

How can I tell wordpress which template to use?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it by putting this into the loop:

```
<?php if (has_term( $_GET["lang"], 'sprache' )) { ?>
```

I was then able to creat links like .../autor/steve-perry/?lang=englisch to filter the search results the way I wanted to.